# Error on during installing opendaylight Hydrogen live edition

Tags: opendaylight

I want to install `OpenDayLight hydrogen` edition.

I install JVM and use the following command to determine JVM installation directory:

```
export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64"
and then have use following command to install OpenDayLight:
sudo ./run.sh -Xmx1024m
```

But following error has been shown:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
!ENTRY org.opendaylight.controller.sal-binding-api 4 0 2017-12-25 04:47:30.779
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The bundle "org.opendaylight.controller.sal-binding-api_1.0.0 [149]" could not be resolved. Reason: Missing Constraint: Import-Package: org.opendaylight.controller.md.sal.common.api; version="[1.0.0,2.0.0)"
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.getResolverError(AbstractBundle.java:1332)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.getResolutionFailureException(AbstractBundle.java:1316)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:323)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1176)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)

!ENTRY org.opendaylight.controller.statistics.northbound 4 0 2017-12-25 04:47:30.787
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The bundle "org.opendaylight.controller.statistics.northbound_0.4.1 [150]" could not be resolved. Reason: Missing Constraint: Import-Package: com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.base; version="[2.3.0,3.0.0)"
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.getResolverError(AbstractBundle.java:1332)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.getResolutionFailureException(AbstractBundle.java:1316)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:323)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1176)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)

!ENTRY org.opendaylight.controller.sal-binding-util 4 0 2017-12-25 04:47:30.800
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The bundle "org.opendaylight.controller.sal-binding-util_1.0.0 [151]" could not be resolved. Reason: Missing Constraint: Import-Package: org.opendaylight.controller.md.sal.common.api; version="[1.0.0,2.0.0)"
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.getResolverError(AbstractBundle.java:1332)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.getResolutionFailureException(AbstractBundle.java:1316)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:323)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1176)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
```

Please help me to solve these error.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you trying to install the Hydrogen version? That was the first version about 4 years ago and has been long since obsolete and no longer maintained/supported. I would suggest using the latest Nitrogen release.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [Tom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8761728/tom-pantelis)’s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48024876/4500798), you can’t use Java 9 to run OpenDaylight, even in its latest release (Nitrogen). You should use Java 8 with Nitrogen.